# How to handle java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jvm, heap-memory

I have an application deployed on Google App Engine and it throws:   `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`  error while executing. I came across some solutions that talk about how to increase the heap size of VM by configuring `eclipse.ini` file, however that works only when application's running locally, so how do we configure and control the heap space size when the application is deployed on Google App Engine, is there a way to access the Java runtime on Google app engine ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The eclipse.ini controls the amount of memory given to Eclipse, not applications you launch from within it.

Comment: You'll probably want to address the heart of the matter: why is the code overflowing the heap? Increasing the heap size is not a real solution, as larger inputs might cause overflows anyway depending on the program.

Comment: I would surely want to know why the code is overflowing the heap only when I'm sure that the heap space allocated in the run time is enough, so is there a way to know what is the heap size on Google App Engine ?

Comment: I haven't used GAE myself, but I believe https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings?hl=en holds the answer. Probably 128MB

Comment: It looks like Java machine is running out of memory, so will increase Java heap size. To that checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Comment: you can change it from admin console, under Application Settings tab of you Appengine app. Up to 1Gb (`F4_1G` instance) from default 128m (`F1` instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to configure memory for an application deployed on GAE, previously there were options to select a Front end Instance Class which is shown in screenshot below :

[image]

However these options are no longer available on the GAE admin console, the screenshot below shows that GAE has fewer options now :

[image]

Now the same Front end Instance Class needs to be configured using a XML file as part of the application as decribed on this page : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration

Answer (score 0):

As already stated you can increase your frontend instances to larger instances on the "Application Settings" (on the old GAE console) , unfortunately that might not really help you.

If you really need memory intensive operations consider moving taht portion of your app to a [managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) or a [Cloud compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) instance where you have more control over the environment in which your app runs.